# Combine date and hourly values in columns into timeseries (and reverse) in R

Tags: r, csv, time-series, import-from-csv

I have some CSV data in the format:

```
date, total, avg, hour00, hour01, ... hour23
```

This I would like to expand into a time series in the format:

```
date-time(date + hourXX), (value of hourXX)
```

Example input:

```
      date, total, avg, hour00, hour01, hour02, hour03, ..., hour23
2013-01-27,   240,  10,      5,     15,     20,      0, ...,     14
2013-01-28,   305,  15,      9,     18,     17,     12, ...,     16
```

Example output (data.frame object):

```
       date-time, hourXX
2013-01-27 00:00,      5
2013-01-27 01:00,     15
2013-01-27 02:00,     20
2013-01-27 03:00,      0
...
2013-01-27 23:00,     14
2013-01-28 00:00,     15
...
```

So each value in column hour00-hour23 corresponds to the sample taken at date+hourXX.

I know how to do this in sql, where I would make 24 UNION ALL, each selecting a column, but is there a 'smart' way of doing this in **R** (or maybe some experts out there who even knows a better way of doing this in sql).

As a bonus question, is there a way of doing this in reverse (taking a time series and converting it into hour00-hour23 format)?

Comment: The desired output looks more like a zoo object than a time series object, and what is "doing this in reverse"? (it's also a waste of time for you to advertise this as "advanced R")

Comment: zoo object: Thanks, I'll take a look - reverse: the opposite transformation from timeseries to column-based by hour - "advanced R": sorry about this - I could just not find this in the R standard packages nor after extended googling

Answer (score 1):

Here is a brute-force approach.  It is using your example, with hours c(0:3,23).  Note the comment on the first line of the function, to reshape the data when all hours of the day are present.

```
f <- function(df) {
  hours <- paste0('hour', sprintf('%02d', c(0:3,23)))  ## paste0('hour', sprintf('%02d', 0:23))
  df <- reshape(df, direction='long', varying=hours, sep='')[c('date', 'time', 'hour')]
  df[['date-time']] <- paste0(df$date, ' ', sprintf('%02d', df$time), ':00')
  df <- df[c('date-time', 'hour')]
  df[order(df[['date-time']]),]
}

df <- read.csv(header=T, text="      date, total, avg, hour00, hour01, hour02, hour03, hour23
2013-01-27,   240,  10,      5,     15,     20,      0, 14
2013-01-28,   305,  15,      9,     18,     17,     12, 16")

f(df)
##             date-time hour
## 1.0  2013-01-27 00:00    5
## 1.1  2013-01-27 01:00   15
## 1.2  2013-01-27 02:00   20
## 1.3  2013-01-27 03:00    0
## 1.23 2013-01-27 23:00   14
## 2.0  2013-01-28 00:00    9
## 2.1  2013-01-28 01:00   18
## 2.2  2013-01-28 02:00   17
## 2.3  2013-01-28 03:00   12
## 2.23 2013-01-28 23:00   16
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I am guessing you wanted. If not, then please post an example that represents the problem better:

```
require(zoo)
txt <- scan(textConnection("2013-01-27, 240, 10, 5, 15, 20, 0"), what="character", sep=",") vals=txt[-(1:2)]> dt <- as.POSIXct(txt[1], format="%Y-%m-%d")
zoo(vals, order.by=seq(dt, by="1 hour", length=length(vals) ) )

2013-01-27 00:00:00 2013-01-27 01:00:00 2013-01-27 02:00:00 
                 10                   5                  15 
2013-01-27 03:00:00 2013-01-27 04:00:00 
                 20                   0
```